# English equivalent to the Arabic idiom 'soak it and drink its water'?

Tags: idiom-requests

There is a common Arabic idiom, which literally translated says:

> *Soak it and drink its water*

It can said about pretty much anything, to express a kind of contemptuous indifference.

For example, when Hassan Naseralah was informed Hezbollah had been included in the European Union's list of terrorist groups, he made a speech where he said "*You can soak your list and drink its water*".

It's similar to the English idiom "*you can shove it up your a$$ for all I care*", except in Arabic the phrase is formal, not vulgar.

Is there a formal, or at least non-vulgar, analogous idiom in English which expresses contemptuous indifference, belittlement, and scornful dismissal?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by this phrase. Can you elaborate on the sentiment? Provide a few examples?

Comment: I remember the American press using it to metaphrase Hassan Naseralah  speech. Hassan Naseralah Hezbollah were included in the EU terror list, he responded by saying 'soak your terror list and drink its water'. It is a common arabic idiom, meaning something I am not moved by a scintilla amout/I don't care might refer to smth like shove it up your ***. But it is formal. It is belittling and scornful.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I don't know this usage, but it seems to derive from [Some Muslims ... write some Quran verses on papers using Saffron, then soak it and drink its water](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/qirwah-ruqya-%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A9-%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A9.2224273/) Are you asking us to explain *exactly* what it supposedly "means" (probably just a matter of opinion), or seeking alternative (and more well-known) idiomatic usages for the general context of contemptuously dismissing something?

Comment: @FumbleFingers After his clarification, I think OP is seeking a formal (or at least not vulgar) alternative to the phrase *You can take your X and stuff it*.

Comment: Fumble fingers, I have never heard of that. I am not asking that. This is a common reprehesible and degrading idiom.

Comment: @Dan: Is there meaningfully a "formal" way of contemptuously dismissing something? Maybe Pierre-Simon Laplace's [*I had no need of that hypothesis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_Laplace)?

Comment: Actually, that ritual of soaking the paper in water and drinking the water sounds more like what someone would do to "internalize" the words on the paper or "take it to heart".  I'm not seeing that as belittling though...

Comment: @KristinaLopez But apparently that's not the way it's used in Arabic. It means something like "*stick it where the sun don't shine*". Which also makes sense: *I don't care what you do with his thing, you can do the most absurd thing possible to it, for all I care*.

Comment: I was once told that [Muslims soak the ages of the Qu'ran in water and drink it](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=7852) for medicinal purposes. This seems like a related statement. It looks like the practice is disputed, so something relating to superstition may work. If this is the origin of the phrase, I'm tempted to suggest something related to [snake oil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snake+oil), which shysters used to sell as a cure-all medicine but it's not expressly religious I'm unsure if this idiom indicates disbelief like Snake Oil does.

Answer (score 6):

That list is not worth the paper it is printed/written on.

> not worth the paper something is printed on  also not worth the paper
>   something is written on
>
> = to have no value or importance He's got a degree from an online university that's not worth the paper it's printed on. The landlord's
>   promises were not worth the paper they were written on.
>
> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+worth+the+paper+is+printed+on

Answer (score 5):

**[Stick that in your pipe and smoke it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/put-stick-that-in-your-pipe-and-smoke-it)**

Not exactly a match as it's often used as a counter argument, but has the same feeling.

> that terror list is a load of made up rubbish! Stick that in your pipe and smoke it!

Answer (score 1):

We'd say "I couldn't care less."

Note that it is properly "couldn't", and that this makes sense. People may say "could" instead if they are uneducated, illogical, or having speech problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may say **I don't give a hoot about this**.

Also *"not give two hoots"* or *"not give a damn"*.

- It means that you don't care about something at all and  show no
  concern or interest.
- For example, "I don’t give a hoot about what
  people think of me".